# Javascript: wait for for loop async function before going to next item in loop

Tags: javascript

In this script

```js
    const build_ids = [ {val:1},{val:2} ]

    for (let id in build_ids) {
        console.log(build_ids[id]);
        getStash(build_ids[id], (build) => {
            console.log(build)
        });
    }

    function getStash(build, cb) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            cb(`proccessing ${build.val}`);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

You will see that the order

```
{ val: 1 }
{ val: 2 }
proccessing 1
proccessing 2
```

How can I modify the code so the for loop waits on the async function before going to the next? The outcome in the desired situation would look like this...

```
{ val: 1 }
proccessing 1
{ val: 2 }
proccessing 2
```

I maybe asked the question wrong. Please also let me know what i need to be asking.

Comment: Have `getStash` return a `Promise` and then `await` it on every iteration

Comment: See the first answer and how it uses `await` to wait for the `Promise` to resolve before moving on to the next line (you want to do the same thing)

Comment: i dont suppose you could convert my code to a promise?